# Hide divs with no val (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX call where I get data from back-end and  get to divs.

Here is my code of AJAX call:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    question_block();
});
function question_block() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Interwier")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var email = result;
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var question =
                    '<div class="activeQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question1 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question2 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question3 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question4 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question5 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question6 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question7 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question8 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question9 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question10 +
                        '</div>';

                count_blocks();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Smth wrong in controller");
        }
    });
}
```

But some of blocks can have no values. I need to hide them

How I can do this via Javascript?

Thank's for help so much.

Comment: you can use `.contains` like `$( "div:contains('')" ).css("display","none")`

Comment: Evaluate `email[i].Question#` and when empty apply a class to the generated `div` that applies `display:none` as required or skipp adding that `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function to check if `div` is `empty`.

```
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el.html())
}
$('.hiddenQue').each(function(){
    if(isEmpty($(this)))
       $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After appending the content use `$('.hiddenQue:empty').hide()`.

Alternatively, amend your logic so that no div is created where the `QuestionX` property is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think I can propose two solutions:
The first one is to not create div if there is no data for it, something like this:

```
email[i].Question2 ? 
'<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' + email[i].Question2 + '</div>' : '' +
```

The second one is to add some class to div which has no data in the same way as in the first solution.

Comment: I think. It more right to not create div if it don't have data. But I don't understand your code

Comment: Its a ternary operation, short version of if...else, if you want:
    <bool expression> ? <true condition> : <false condition>

Comment: maybe you will need to enclose complex expressions in <true condition> to a braces

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code `$('.activeQue').find('.hiddenQue:empty').hide();` after `question_block()` method.